# Values of $\Phi_n(-1)$

Tags: number-theory, conjectures, cyclotomic-polynomials

Let

$$\Phi_n(x) = \prod_{0<k\leq n, \gcd(k,n)=1}(x-e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}})$$

be the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial. By observation it seems that cyclotomic polynomials when evaluated at $x=-1$ give the following

$$\Phi_n(-1) = \begin{cases} 2 \quad \text{if} \quad n = 2^k, k>1\in \mathbb{N}\\
p \quad \text{if} \quad n = 2p\\
1 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

where $p$ denotes a prime $(> 2)$. The first few cases are
$$\Phi_1(-1) = -2$$
$$\Phi_2(-1) = 0$$
$$\Phi_3(-1) = 1$$
$$\Phi_4(-1) = 2$$
$$\Phi_5(-1) = 1$$
$$\Phi_6(-1) = 3$$
$$\Phi_7(-1) = 1$$
$$\Phi_8(-1) = 2$$
however we will only consider $n>2$ for the conjecture.

This I thought was quite weird at first as it seems like a very simple pattern for something as complicated as the coefficients of cyclotomic polynomials. I managed to prove the first two cases, and will share the short proofs below, but am unsure of how to tackle the last case. I don't have any way to check for high values of $n$ other than calculation, and so I apologise in advance if there is a counterexample to this conjecture that can easily be checked with a computer. Below are the proofs for $n= 2^k$ and $n=2p$,

### $n = 2^k$

By Möbius inversion we get
$$\Phi_n(x) = \prod_{d\mid n}(x^d-1)^{\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)}$$

Since $\mu(2^n) = 0$ for $n>1$ with $\mu(2)=-1$, therefore
$$\Phi_{2^n}(x) = (x^{2^n}-1)(x^{2^{n-1}}-1)^{-1} = x^{2^{n-1}}+1$$
$$\Phi_{2^n}(-1) = 2$$

### $n = 2p$

We can use the following [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)
$$\Phi_{2p}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}(-1)^kx^k$$
$$ = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1}1 = p$$

But for the 'otherwise' case, I don't know how to approach it. It seems to general to approach in any specific way using identities or by looking at the values of $\mu(d)$ as that would require more information about the divisors of $n$. Any help or a proof/counterexample is appreciated!

Comment: Yes. Forgot to add that in. Thanks

Comment: Essentially, do the same. EG In the odd case, we have $ \prod_{d \mid n } \Phi_d (-1) = (-1)^p - 1 = -2$. This gives us $ \Phi_{-1} (-1) = - 2 $ (not mentioned) and otherwise $ \Phi_{odd} ( -1) = 1 $ (by induction).

Comment: I did added that $n>2$ as that was what I was originally looking at. I will add it in as a case anyway

Comment: My point is that knowing $\Phi_1, \Phi_2$, alongside $ ( x^{2n} + 1 ) / ( x + 1 ) $ helps you determine the rest of the values.

Comment: @CalvinLin I'm not sure I see how without requiring knowledge about the  divisors of $n$ considered in the otherwise case. If you have a solution, you could post it and I will accept it if it is what I'm looking for

Comment: Did you see how I did the odd case above?

Comment: I'm trying to work through it but I think I'm missing something. When dealing with a an example like $n= 2\cdot 3\cdot p_1\cdot p_2^2$ I have terms that I cannot just conclude are $=1$ as it could be that two terms $=-1$ and their multiplication results in $1$. If you can, please write out an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the notation $ f(x) \mid_{x = a } $ to denote we are evaluating $f(x)$ at $ x= a$. This allows me to list out $f(x)$, then evaluate it.

All that we use is $ \prod _{d\mid n } \Phi_d(x) = x^n - 1$.

1. $ \Phi_1( -1) = x-1 \mid_{x=-1} = -2$
2. $ \Phi_2 (-1) = \frac{x^2 - 1 } { x-1} \mid_{x=-1} = x+1 \mid_{x=-1} =  0 $
3. $\Phi_p ( -1) = 1 $ for primes $p$.

   - $ \Phi_1 (-1) \times \Phi_p (-1) = x^p - 1 \mid_{x=-1}  = - 2$
4. $ \Phi_n ( -1) = 1$ for odd $ n > 1$

   - Proof by strong induction on the number of divisors $k$ of $n$.
   - Base case: $ k = 2$ is done above.
   - Suppose $n$ has $k+1$ divisors. Then

$$-2 = x^n - 1 \mid _{x=-1} = 
\Phi_1(-1) \times  \Phi_n (-1) \times \prod_{d \mid n, d\neq 1, d\neq n} \Phi_d(-1) = (-2) \times \Phi_n(-1) \times 1 .$$

When naively extending this argument to even $n$, we run into an issue where $\Phi_2(-1) = 0 $ and $ x^{n} - 1 = 0 $, so we can't determine what $\Phi_n(-1)$ will be.
To deal with this, we account explicitly for those zeros via
$$ \frac{ x^{n} - 1 } {x +1 } \mid_{x=-1} = \prod_{d \mid n, d \neq 2 } \Phi_{d} ( - 1 ).$$
So, to get to $ \Phi_n(-1)$, we have to evaluate the LHS.
Let $ n = 2^k m$, where $m$ is odd. Then,

$$ \begin{array} {l l ll } \frac{ x^{n} - 1 } { x + 1 }\mid_{x=-1}  & = \frac{ x^n - 1 } { x^{2^k} - 1 }\mid_{x=-1} & \times & \frac{ x^{2^k} - 1 } { x + 1 }\mid_{x=-1} \\
& = (x^{2^k(m-1) } + x^{2^k(m-2) } + \ldots + x^{2^k } + 1 ) & \times & (x-1)(1+x^2)(1+x^4) \ldots ( 1 + x^{2^{k-1} } )  \\
& = m & \times &  -2^{k} \\
& = - n \\
\end{array}$$

Corollaries:

6. Quick observation that since $\frac{ x^{n} - 1 } {x +1 } \mid_{x=-1}$ is non-zero, hence so are the individual terms $\prod_{d \mid n, d \neq 2 } \Phi_{d} ( - 1 )$. (This should be obvious beforehand.) Thus, we don't have any more issues to deal with, and can iteratively calculate $ \Phi_n(-1)$.
7. $\Phi_{2^k} ( -1) = 2 $ for $ k > 1 $

   - Proof by induction. $-2^k = \prod_{i \neq 1 } \Phi_{2^k} (-1) = (-2) \times 2^{k-2} \times \Phi_{2^k} (-1) $.
8. $ \Phi_{2p^k} (-1) = p$ for odd prime $ p$

   - Similar proof by induction.
   - Note that this differs from OP's conjecture. We can check that $\Phi_{18} (-1) = x^6 - x^3 + 1 \mid_{x=-1} = 3$.
9. $\Phi_{2n} (-1) = 1 $ for any non-prime power $ n > 1$.

   - Essentially do a proof by strong induction per point 4.
   - Notice that for $ n = \prod p_i ^ { a _ i } $, we have $\Phi_1 (-1) \times \prod_{p^a \mid m, p^a \neq 1 } \Phi_{2p^a} ( -1 ) = -n$, and all of the other non $\Phi_{2n}(-1)$ terms contribute $1$ to the product by induction, hence $ \Phi_{2n} (-1) = 1 $.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now

Answer (score 1):

First note that $\Phi_n(-1)=0$ if and only if $n=2$. This is immediate from your definition
$$\Phi_n(X)=\hspace{-10pt}\prod_{\substack{1\leq d\leq n\\\gcd(d,n)=1}}\hspace{-10pt}(X-e^{\frac{2\pi d}{n}i}),$$
because $e^{\frac{2\pi d}{n}i}=-1$ implies $\tfrac dn=\tfrac12$ given that $1\leq d\leq n$, and then $\gcd(d,n)=1$ implies $d=1$ and $n=2$.

For the proof we only require a few of the most basic identities for cyclotomic polynomials:

1. If $n$ is an odd positive integer then $\Phi_{2n}(X)=\Phi_n(-X)$.
2. If $k$ is a positive integer and $p$ an odd prime number then $\Phi_{p^k}(X)=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}X^{jp^{k-1}}$.
3. If $n=p^km$ is a positive integer with $m$ coprime to $p$ then $\Phi_n(X)=\Phi_{pm}(X^{p^{k-1}})$.
4. If $p$ is a prime number and $m$ is coprime to $p$ then $\Phi_{pm}(X)=\frac{\Phi_m(X^p)}{\Phi_m(X)}$.

If you are not familiar with these results, it is an instructive exercise to prove them. They can also be found on the [Wikipedia page on cyclotomic polyonomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial#Easy_cases_for_computation), the key observation being that
$$X^n-1=\prod_{d\mid n}\Phi_d(X).$$

Now let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $p$ be the largest prime factor of $n$, and write $n=p^km$ with $k$ maximal, so that $m$ is coprime to $p$. Then by identities $(3)$ and $(4)$ we have
$$\Phi_n(X)=\Phi_{pm}(X^{p^{k-1}})=\frac{\Phi_m(X^{p^k})}{\Phi_m(X^{p^{k-1}})}.$$
If $m>2$ then $p$ is odd and we can plug in $\Phi_m((-1)^{p^i})=\Phi_m(-1)\neq0$ to find that $\Phi_{p^km}(-1)=1$.

If $n=2p^k$ for some odd prime $p$ then by identities $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have
$$\Phi_n(X)=\Phi_{p^k}(-X)=\sum_{i=0}^{p-1}(-X)^{ip^{k-1}},$$
and so plugging in $X=-1$ yields $\Phi_n(-1)=p$.

If $n=p^k$ for a prime number $p$, then plugging in $X=-1$ in identity $(2)$ shows that

- If $p=2$ and $k=1$ then $\Phi_n(-1)=0$, as mentioned before.
- If $p=2$ and $k>2$ then $\Phi_n(-1)=2$.
- If $p>2$ then $\Phi_n(-1)=1$.